# Is there a way I can plot my data as an animated graph with respect to time?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking to create an animation that plots data onto a graph so it appears on screen gradually.

My data comes in the form of a row vector, where the actual values in the vector will be plotted against their position in the vector.

Thanks.